# How to test componentWillReceiveProps method in react component

Tags: reactjs, testing, sinon, enzyme

I want to test the componentWillReceiveProps method and see the path for current web page. I tried to use the following code to test the method, but it always throw an error.

```
Invariant Violation: A <Router> may have only one child element
```

I'm wondering what I should do to solve that error? Here is what I have tried so far.

```
class WrappedComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.user_id) {
      this.props.history.replace('/login');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>WrappedComponent</div>
  }
}

describe('AuthenticationHOC', () => {
  describe('authenticationRequired', () => {
    let props;
    const shallowWrapper = () => {
      return shallow(
        <MemoryRouter>
          withRouter(authenticationRequired(<WrappedComponent {...props} />))
        </MemoryRouter>
      )
    }

    it('renders the wrapped component', () => {
      let wrapper = shallowWrapper()
      expect(wrapper.contains(<WrappedComponent {...props} />)).toBe(true)
    })

    describe("when user_id doesn't exist", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
          user_id: ''
        }
      });
      it('should go to the login page', () => {
        //how to test the method componentWillReceiveProps
        let wrapper = shallowWrapper().dive();
        wrapper.setProps({
          user_id: '12312412'
        });
      //  expect(spy.calledOnce).toBe(true);
        expect(window.href).toBe("/login");
      })
    })

    describe("when user_id do exist", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
          user_id: 'something'
        }
      });
      it('should not go to other page', () => {
        let wrapper = shallowWrapper();
        expect(window.href).toBe("/");
      })
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't mock `componentWillReceiveProps` as this is an implemntation detail that we don't care about.

Instead you will need to mock out history somehow (not sure, look at react-router docs maybe) or hopefully you can just check the current href as hopefully when you use `history.replace` it might just change the href immediately.

Use enzymes `dive()` to dive through your Higher order components and use `setProps` on the wrapper component.

You might need to chain dive() again depending on how many HOC's you have wrapped.

```
// TODO add tests that verify history.replace was called
describe("when user_id doesn't exist", () => {    
  beforeEach(() => {
    props.user_id = ''
  });

  const wrapper = shallowWrapper().dive();
  const user_id = 'testId';

  wrapper.setProps({ user_id });

  expect(window.href).toBe('/login');
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have an error when I tried your solution, I always get the error Invariant Violation: A <Router> may have only one child element
Can you take look at my updated code and help me solve this test?

Comment: Try wrapping `withRouter` in a div. Also make sure `authenticationRequired` returns only a single child

Comment: Yeah, now the error was solved. But it seems that the value for window.href is always undefined....

Comment: I tried `window.location.href`. The current location is always http://localhost/. So how to trigger the method componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: @Darren Is it actually replacing the history? Try debugging it with console.logs to see.

Comment: yeah it is not replacing the history. That method just simply didn't trigger